# How to deal with different dimensions input for neural network?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, neural-network

I try to code a NN that predicts the cross product of 2 vectors in R^3.
XTrain has 3:2:1000 dimensions and is an array of matrices 3x2 (or basically 2 vectors 3x1). YTrain is a 3:1000 array. Here is my code:

```
Xtrain = zeros(3,2,1000);
Ytrain = zeros(3,1000);
for c = 1:1000
    v1 = -1 + (1+1)*rand(3,1);
    v2 = -1 + (1+1)*rand(3,1);
    C = cross(v1,v2);
    m = [v1, v2];
    Xtrain(:,:,c) = m;
    Ytrain(:,c) = C;
end
net = feedforwardnet([3 2]);
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'purelin';
net = train(net, Xtrain, Ytrain);
```

However Matlab gives 'Inputs X is not two-dimensional.'  error. What is the best solution here?

Comment: considering its just a feedforward net, why not just put the inputs as 1 array of 6x1?

Comment: ah that's a good idea!

Comment: @Ander Biguri thank you for the idea! After small changes it works. If you answer I will be glad to accept your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In feedforward neural networks inputs are always 1D.

So unroll your 2D input into a 1D array, and just train with that!